# How to add local files in Visual Studio to an Azure LocalResource "folder"?

Tags: asp.net, azure

I'm wondering how to get files *into* a "LocalResource" storage on an Azure web instance using Visual Studio?  I have an Azure web project handling the deployment specifics for a web service.  (see relevant ServiceDefintion.csdef file fragment below)

The Azure project for the web service already has a couple of extra files copied to a LocalResource folder called InstallLogs to make sure the 4.52 .NET runtime is installed on the azure machine. However, somehow the "bin" folder added to support these filed resources works in relation the to that named path in a way I don't understand. (I used Azure doc examples to get that part working.)

What I can't figure out is how to add file resources to a second LocalResource folder I added called OpenNLPbins.  The LocalResource is being created and I can get a valid path to it runtime via remote debugging, but no matter how long I look around I can't figure out how I am supposed to specify *in Visual Studio* that a bunch of local binary files ("EnglishSD.nbin") as an example get deployed into the OpenNLPbins "folder" when I publish?

Any ideas or help appreciated?

Thanks,
Dave Gerding

... from azure service csdef...

```
<LocalResources>
<LocalStorage name="InstallLogs" sizeInMB="5" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" />
<LocalStorage name="OpenNLPbins" sizeInMB="150" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" />      
</LocalResources>
<Startup>
<Task commandLine="install.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple">
<Environment>
<Variable name="PathToInstallLogs">
<RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/CurrentInstance/LocalResources/LocalResource[@name='InstallLogs']/@path" />
</Variable>
</Environment>
</Task>
</Startup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use local resource folders from within Visual Studio. Because these are folders located on the instance, after your application is deployed.

You can only access those folders from your code, by using the `RoleEnvironment`'s static method [GetLocalResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.getlocalresource.aspx).

What, at best you can do, is to deploy your files in an [Azure Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/). Then either use the `RoleEntryPoint`'s [OnStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.onstart.aspx) method to download your files into the local resource folder. Or use a [startup task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh180155.aspx) to do so.

There is good tutorial on [best practices for Stratup tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj129545.aspx), which includes reference on [how to use local resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974419.aspx) in a startup task.

As a last resort, and I never advice on doing so, you can include those files in your project, marking them as "Content" and "Copy always to output folder" and you can use the RoleEntryPoint class to copy these files before your instance is started (OnStart).

I would always, when possible, prefer to have the files in the Blob Storage and download from there.